# Possible orders of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and the order of $H$ is $10$. Let also $a \in G$ and $a^6 \in H$. What are the possible orders of $a$?

Since $a^6 \in H$, then $a^{6n} \in H$, for any integer $n$. Since $|H|= 10$, then $a^{60} = e$. Therefore $|a|$ will divide $60$.

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed further?

Comment: You now have $12$ options for $|a|$. Write them all out, and for each one, see whether you can find an example with that order. I would start looking for examples with $G=\Bbb Z_{60}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be the order of $a$. Then the order of $a^6$ is $m=\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n,6)}$ and it must divide $10$.

- $m=1$ iff $n=\gcd(n,6)$ iff $n \in \{1,2,3,6\}$.
- $m=2$ iff $n=2\gcd(n,6)$ iff $n \in \{4,12\}$.
- $m=5$ iff $n=5\gcd(n,6)$ iff $n \in \{5,10,15,30\}$.
- $m=10$ iff $n=10\gcd(n,6)$ iff $n \in \{20,60\}$.

All $12$ divisors of $60$ appear as possible candidates. They are all realized in the cyclic group of order $60$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i can see which points i was missing

Comment: I think in the m=2 case , 2 should not be there in the set .

Comment: @blueboy, you're right, thanks.